# Strange behavior for $(window).blur event in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera, blur

I have this script for checking if tab is leaved:

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_url",
        data: { leaved_tab:"true" },
    });
});
```

Then I log POST data on server side.

There is strange behavior in Opera in this certain case: if I'm currently on some another tab/page, then I switch to tab/page where that js code is, and then if leave that page, opera sends event 3 times instead of 1.

Code works correct in Chrome and Firefox,   but why there is 3 `blur` event for Opera, in case what I described above, I don't understand.

Opera Version:  48.0.2685.50

Some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect there's some event bubbling happening somewhere. Check the `currentTarget` property each time the event is triggered.

Comment: There is an event instead of blur https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API